# How to upload xml file to a path in wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I'm writing a custom plugin to import data from a custom xml to a WordPress database. After activating plugin and uploading xml file, it is showing error "sorry, only xml files are allowed". I have used only xml file. but I'm not sure why the file is not getting uploaded to location. I echoed location and file name, but file name is not being displayed. I'm using php code for upload section. not sure I'm following right way. here is the snapshot and code

[image]

Here is the code url: [code here](http://pastebin.com/HQGvb75K)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've not used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which may be the first reason your file is not being uploaded.
See here:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Another thing, instead of uploading the files to theme directory, upload it to upload directory. See this for details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir

Comment: Thnak you. both the modifications you mentioned worked well. files are getting uploaded and showing data is successfully imported. But i`m not seing any updated info in database, I tried echoing values. but it is giving blank values. i have updated files in paste bin. 

http://pastebin.com/HQGvb75K

Comment: Is the file upload successful? Did you check it in the `uploads` folder? I think you need to use this code in line 30: `$target_dir = $uri['path'];`.

Comment: Thanks again   @gskhanal ., i replaced wordpress insert functionality with normal php functionality and things are working fine and data is getting inserted properly. but may I know why we defined 'path' keyword "$uri['path']" for $target_dir?

Comment: `wp_upload_dir()` function returns array which contains path & url of current month folder, path & url of uploads directory along with other things. So, you need to pass where you want your file to be uploaded. Please read the documentation for more details.